# .Net Uploading an image - Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to upload an image together with a form, which works fine on localhost but after deploying to Microsoft azure I keep getting 500 internal server error. After I commented out the code below the form data was saved to the DB successfully. So I can't figure out why upload works on local but not on azure.

```
//upload image
        var postedFile = httpRequest.Files["Picture"];
        if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //create custom filename
            imageName = new string(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(" ", "-");
            imageName = imageName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + imageName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
```

Comment: So it works on localhost but not when published, smells like user permissions in the server. What user do you have configured as the application pool's identity? Does that user has write permission on the path the file is created / saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to create the directory first with `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);`.

Check implementation below;

```
var postedFile = httpRequest.Files["Picture"];
if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
   //create custom filename
   imageName = new string(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(" ", "-");
   imageName = imageName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);

   // create directory
   var path = Server.MapPath("~/Upload");
   if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
   {
       System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
   }

   // then save
   var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + imageName);
   postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I missed